# Graphql get all commits between 2 tags

Tags: graphql, github-graphql

I want to list all the commits between 2 tags

If i try to get commits between 2 dates on which tags point, i even get the commits from other branch which was merged after 2nd commit but made between those 2 dates.

I will like to get some thing equivalent of `git log  v0.0.21...v0.0.32` in GraphQL api or REST api